# Displaying the drawing in html

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

js and draw anything on canvas onmousemove events.. My question is how can I add a button that displays the drawing exactly under the canvas ? It also has to be clear the previous drawing and display the each drawing one under the other.
To sum up you have a empty canvas , draw something , click the button , display all of them one under the other..

here is a link that u can try drawing I wanted to add a button just below of it to do the operation that I explained
http://www.webdeneme.net/1.html

Comment: you forgot to post your code?dint you..

Comment: I've just added the link you can see the source .. I couldnt do the indentation properly in here

Comment: try to make jsfiddle, so that we can experiment with your code, and explain the question again please